# Laravel model fillable issue

Tags: laravel, model

I have model User I write fillable fields:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'photo','color', 'email','admin','jobtitle','phone','mobile','restaurant','address','address2','city','state','zip','country','url','twitter','facebook','capacity','email_for_invoices','vat', 'test', 'type','tos','vatrate','lat','lng','booking','validity', 'photobg','viaurl', 'subdomain','sample_menu','sample_menu_url'];
```

but when I make `return $user`

As a response I got:

[image]

**So all fields are not fillable (etc. 'test')? Why?**
Is Laravel model limited to 30 fillable fields ? or something else makes me problem?

Comment: Are data saved in DB or not ? maybe it is not just in the array

Comment: I have 'test' column in the database ...

Comment: check `test` column value is saved in DB or not

Comment: Yes its saved: https://www.screencast.com/t/dxGEvz1Wp78

Comment: What does $user = ?

Comment: $user = User::findOrFail($id);

Comment: Show user model

Comment: if it saved, then it's already fallable

Comment: but I make 'test' field from phpmyadmin

Comment: It's a pain to list all your `$fillable` attributes. You can get rid of those `$fillable` and just declare your `protected $guarded = [] ` attributes.

Comment: I dont have it...